# Git - Protocol Error - Strange character

Tags: windows, git, vagrant

I have failed at google, please help.

I have a base Windows 8 OS running Vagrant with Ubuntu 14 (32bit).

When running

```
git add -A
```

or

```
git add *
```

I get the following message:

```
addresses▒show.blade.php: Protocol error
```

I am developing on Windows but gitting through Vagrant.

I can commit and push, but I am sure something is wrong and would like to resolve it before it really causes a problem later.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I have the same error, anyone fixed this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a strange character between 'addresses' and 'show.blade.php' which may be causing problems in the content of the added tree. You can run `git fsck` to see if the state of the .git repository has been corrupted. Alternatively you may have redefined `add` as an alias to do something like 'add-and-push'?